# getting a default value from pandas dataframe when a key is not present

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe multi-index where each key is a tuple of two. Currently, the order of the values in the key matters: `df[(k1,k2)]` is not the same as `df[('k2,k1')]`. also, sometimes `k1,k2` exists in the dataframe while `k2,k1` does not.

I'm trying to average the values of a certain columns for those two entries. currently, Im doing this:

```
if (k1,k2) in df.index.values and not (k2,k1) in df.index.values:
    x = df[(k1,k2)]
if (k2,k1) in df.index.values and not (k1,k2) in df.index.values:
    x = df[(k2,k1)]
if (k2,k1) in df.index.values and (k1,k2) in df.index.values:
    x = (df[(k2,k1)] + df[k1,k2])/2
```

This is quit ugly... Im looking for something like a get_defualt method we have on a dictionary.. Is there something like this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ix` index access and `mean` function handle this for you. Fetch the two tuples from `df.ix` and apply the mean function to it: non existing keys are returned as nan values, and mean ignores nan values by default:

```
In [102]: df
Out[102]: 
   (26, 22)  (10, 48)  (48, 42)  (48, 10)  (42, 48)
a       311       NaN       724       879        42

In [103]: df.ix[:,[(10, 48), (48, 10)]].mean(axis=1)
Out[103]: 
a    879
dtype: float64

In [104]: df.ix[:,[(42, 48), (48, 42)]].mean(axis=1)
Out[104]: 
a    383
dtype: float64

In [105]: df.ix[:,[(26, 22), (22, 26)]].mean(axis=1)
Out[105]: 
a    311
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Well, that did it! I am still confused by that behavior. if you are trying to retrieve an entry that does not exist, you are getting a key error. If you are trying to retrieve more than one entry, your are getting Nan's for non existing entries. so my problem was trying to retrieve each at the time and not all simultaneously?